# Egyptian fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, fractions

Is it true that any fraction $a/b$ can be written in infinitely many ways as a sum  of different Egyptian fractions (those with denominator equal to 1)?

Comment: You mean numerator equal to 1?

Comment: Yes, it is true, see section $4.1$ [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/egyptian.html). For more you should also first search this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123045/expanding-integers-into-distinct-egyptian-fractions-what-is-the-optimal-way?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @MartinR, I do not think you could use minus. you can only add, where the denominator is positive integer

Comment: @DietrichBurde, if you have read the links and understood them, I would appreciate if you could give a simple proof/answer. The question has not been asked on stackexchange before and it would help others

Comment: But section $4.1$ has a simple proof. Why don't you copy it?

Comment: Just for fun. $a/b = 1/x + 1/y + ...$,  then $a/b = ac/bc = c/x + c/y + ...$, and you expand $a/b = 1/x + 1/x + ... $ (c times) $+ 1/y + 1/y + ... $(c times)$ + ...$   Which proves there are infinitely many ways to do this by choosing $c$ what ever integer you like

Comment: There's a Egyptian fractions tag on this site, I suggest you browse it since this topic is very interesting

Answer (score 0):

The key is the identity: $$\frac1b = \frac{1}{b+1} + \frac{1}{b(b+1)}\tag{*1}$$

For any positive rational number $\frac{a}{b}$, you first express it as a sum of reciprocals of positive integers.
$$\frac{a}{b} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{b} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b}}_{a \text{ terms}}$$
Start from any sum of reciprocals, if the corresponding integers are not distinct, pick one of the duplicated integers and apply identity $(*1)$.
Repeat this procedure if the remaining integers are not distinct.
In finitely many steps, this process will terminate. This end result is
an expression of $\frac{a}{b}$ as a sum of reciprocals of distinct positive integers.

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{b_1} + \frac{1}{b_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{b_n}$$

where $b = b_1 < b_2 < \cdots < b_n$.

$b_n$ is the "largest integer" appear in above sum. Apply $(*1)$ to this $b_n$, you obtain a new expression of $\frac{a}{b}$ as a sum of distinct reciprocals with larger "largest integer".

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{b_1} + \frac{1}{b_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{b_n+1} + \frac{1}{b_n(b_n + 1)}$$

Repeat this procedure, you can generate as many sum of reciprocals for $\frac{a}{b}$ as you wish.